# how to give hyperlink to Image Column in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to hyperlink to DataGridViewImageColumn in win forms??

Code Sample from OPs comments:

```
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
dgv.Name = "dgv" + i;
dgv.DataSource = dsMain.Tables[0];
dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

Image image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Small.jpg");
img.Image = image;
img.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Normal;
dgv.Columns.Add(img);
img.HeaderText = "";
img.Name = "img";

tp.Controls.Add(dgv);
```

Comment: Would be helpful to show any code you have so far.

Comment: Nitin, delete your comment and in future edit your questions.

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly mean by this: 'How to hyperlink to DataGridViewImageColumn in win forms??'

Comment: @geepie ..pls read title of the post.

Comment: yes and as OJ said what do you want the link to do. I think you need to give more information on the problem and any errors your experiencing if any.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the link to do? Open a web page?

Just add a click handler to the image.