# hyperlink in DataGridView's column

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to give hyperlink to Image Column in Datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179490/how-to-give-hyperlink-to-image-column-in-datagridview)

can i give hyperlink in DataGridView's column that contains Image.. and after clicking on image, specified url should open ??

Comment: You already asked this question once: [how to give hyperlink to Image Column in Datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179490/how-to-give-hyperlink-to-image-column-in-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Dictionary<Image,string>` to map links to image , and then handle click event on Image cell

```
Dictionary<Image,string> UrlDicationary = new Dictionary<Image, string>();
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.ColumnIndex == your_image_column_index)
     {
         Image image = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value as Image;
         if(image != null)
         {
               string url;
               if(UrlDicationary.TryGetValue(image, out url))
               {
                    Process.Start(url);
               }
         }
     }
}
```

You need to fill dictionary first